# Как сделать цикл выполняющийся каждые X секунд не используя time.sleep()

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как сделать цикл выполняющийся каждые X секунд не используя time.sleep(). Мне не подходит вариант `time.sleep()` потому-что когда выполняется `time.sleep()` окно с программой становится не активным

Comment: запусти в потоке

Comment: @alex как его запустить в потоке

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html

Comment: Вообще ответ зависит от используемой библиотеки для графического интерфейса. В tkinter можно использовать метод after. В других библиотеках возможно свои методы для реализации таймеров есть.

Comment: @insolor PySide 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй использовать threading.

```
def one():
 while True:
  time.sleep(2)
  print('Цикл пройдет')
t1 = Thread(target=one)
t1.start
```

Этот код будет выполняться в отдельном потоке не блокируя основной.